# Unknown CMake command "ign_find_package"

Tags: gazebo-plugin, gazebo-edifice

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I get the same error as in [this post](https://answers.gazebosim.org//question/26770/unknown-cmake-command-ign_find_package/) but I couldn't solve it by just sourcing my ignition workspace.

I installed ignition gazebo edifice with these [instructions](https://gazebosim.org/docs/edifice/install_ubuntu_src).
The place where I build it with `colcon build --merge-install` is `~/workspace`.

Now I tried to recreate the [example plugin](https://gazebosim.org/api/gazebo/5.4/createsystemplugins.html) in another folder `~/ros2_ws/src/plugins/sample_system`.

Then I source the ign workspace with `. ~/workspace/install/setup.bash`
and try to build the ros2_ws with `colcon build` but I get this error

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (ign_find_package):
  Unknown CMake command "ign_find_package".
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/28136/unknown-cmake-command-%22ign_find_package%22./) by [florian.pix](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/81881/florian.pix/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2022-05-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The [system plugin tutorial from ign gazebo](https://gazebosim.org/api/gazebo/2.10/createsystemplugins.html) seems to be incomplete. Before using "ign_find_package" you need to first put in "find_package(ignition-cmake2 REQUIRED)".
Also ign_find_package isn*t needed in every case. For example a basic GUI Plugins CMakeLists.txt could look like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.2 FATAL_ERROR)

if(POLICY CMP0100)
  cmake_policy(SET CMP0100 NEW)
endif()

project(test_plugin)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

find_package(ignition-gazebo5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS gui)

QT5_ADD_RESOURCES(resources_RCC ${PROJECT_NAME}.qrc)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED
  ${PROJECT_NAME}.cc
  ${resources_RCC}
)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PRIVATE ignition-gazebo5::gui
)
```

---

Originally posted by [florian.pix](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/81881/florian.pix/) with karma: 11 on 2022-05-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0